# Getting started with GNOME

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, gnome

Lately I really want to start hacking my Ubuntu.  I looked at installed applications, and 
the "system monitor" is really interesting.  I have downloaded [some code](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/gnome/gnome-system-monitor.html), but after I looked at it, I'm pretty sure I need some help.  I have no idea how to compile, run, and start checking it.

What books, tutorials, or other resources would help me get started?  I have some background with C, C++, and Perl.

Answer (score 1):

It appears currently the most popular option for Gnome development is [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/).

There are some GTK+ tutorials for Gnome [here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk-tutorial/stable/), which are part of the [Gnome Documentation Library](http://library.gnome.org/devel/).

Another option to do Gnome development is the open source .NET platform, [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Hopefully that is enough to get you started. I didn't recommend any books since I would not consider myself knowledgeable enough on GTK+ or Mono to make a worthy recommendation.

Comment: Saying Gtk+ is popular for Gnome development is like saying legs are popular for walking.

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest a fairly new Ubuntu project called [Quickly](https://launchpad.net/quickly), which jumpstarts your coding by writing the [scaffolding of a Python/GTK+ application](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2009/08/quickly-new-rails-like-rapid-development-tools-for-ubuntu.ars) for you... well, uh, *quickly*. Python is fairly strait-forward as modern/dynamic/OOP + functional languages go, so [learning Python](http://arstechnica.com/old/content/2008/12/getting-a-grip-on-python-six-ways-to-learn-online.ars) should not be difficult for you. And the [PyGTK libraries](http://www.pygtk.org/) are quite close to the GTK+, so any time you spend learning them will apply to [GTK+-programming](http://www.linuxheadquarters.com/howto/programming/gtk_examples/index.shtml) in any other language, too.